# Stored Procedure with Datatable as param returns nothing

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, datatable

I have set up a stored procedure which I am passing a data table into and calling directly from Entity Framework.

I have created a Type with the following sql:

```
 CREATE TYPE Regions AS TABLE 
             (      RegionId int, 
                    Region varchar(max),                    
                    BodyId int NULL, 
                    Body varchar(max),
                    AreaId int NULL, 
                    Area varchar(max),   
                    Location varchar(max), 
                    LocationId int
              )
```

My test stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStats]

     @regions  dbo.Regions READONLY 

AS
BEGIN

    SELECT * INTO #tmptble  from @regions  

    Select * from #tmptble


END
```

I am using the following to call the stored procedure:

```
 SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();

            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            param.TypeName = "dbo.Regions";
            param.Value = myDataTable;
            param.ParameterName = "@regions";

return _context.Database.SqlQuery<RegionDetails>("GetStats", param);
```

My datatable is definitely the correct format as I have run this through profiler passing it in to the stored procedure and you can see all the inserts appearing. 
If I generate a test table from all the insert statements the procedure runs fine against that but when I run it with the passed in datatable it just returns no rows.

**EDIT - for further info**
When I run this through profiler I get the following:

```
declare @p3 dbo.Regions

~~~a Load of insert statements of all my datatable data~~~

exec sp_executesql N'GetStats',N'@regions [dbo].[Regions] READONLY',@regions =@p3
```

**UPDATE on the above**
I have been playing around with what is shown in profiler and if I replace

> exec sp_executesql N'GetStats',N'@regions [dbo].[Regions]
>   READONLY',@regions =@p3

with

> EXEC GetStats @p3

Again it works. Has anyone got any clue why?

Comment: Well, if you posted the stored procedure it would be possible to answer this question. Right now it's impossible.

Comment: I don't think the problem is anything wrong with my actual stored procedure, just the calling or passing the datatable as I literally switch out #tmptbl for TESTTable and it works. Is there any specific parts I can post that will help as I cannot post the whole procedure as it's very complicated I think will confuse things.

Comment: Are you trying to insert rows into the passed datatable in the stored procedure?

Comment: I have updated the question with a test stored procedure. I am sending in a datatable as a param so I can insert it to a temporary table so I can join  on it. It seems its not getting there correctly.

Comment: This test procedure is meaningless. Try to either insert the values into a regular table or simply select the values from the table valued parameter and see if you get them back to the c# code.

Comment: select * from @regions. ?? What does bit return ?

Comment: @eranotzap regions is my datatable, I am trying to insert it into a tmp table as per this stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507629/passing-datatable-to-stored-procedure-as-an-argument

Comment: @ZoharPeled I tried inserting my regions into a "proper" table using the stored procedure but there are no rows. I'm not sure how else to describe this, I know I'm missing something

Comment: I know I wondered if maybe your passing an empty table

Comment: @eranotzap I thought that, but I have debugged and it's definitely got something in it and when I run profiler you can see all the data there

Comment: Are your columns in the table in the same order as in the SQL table type definition?

Comment: @BrandonKramer Yes they are. :(

Comment: This seems odd, but try removing the TypeName.  Don't set it and see if that works.  All the examples I see for Stored Procedures do not set TypeName.

Comment: @BrandonKramer Do you mean the typename in the c# or the stored procedure. According to MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx you need to specify a type if its passing a datatable

Comment: Try removing the `param.TypeValue = ...` line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137363/discussion-between-brandon-kramer-and-bex).

Comment: One of the main points of a table valued parameter is you can join to it directly. There is no point in receiving a set of data and immediately copying to a temp table. Just join your paramter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
//create parameter
var param = new SqlParameter("@regions", SqlDbType.Structured);   
param.Value = myDataTable;   
param.TypeName = "dbo.Regions";  

//return result set
return _context.ExecuteFunction<RegionDetails>("dbo.Regions", param);

//OR
//execute stored procedure for inserts, returns rows effective
return _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec dbo.Regions @regions", param);
```

Comment: ExecuteSqlCommand seems only to return an int. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Bex - Revised answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: I dont seem to have an execute function command on my context. Just execute sqlcommand. I have Entity Framework 6.1.1

Comment: Worked it out! Thank you. I needed the parameter name in the call in Entity framwork like so:   return _context.Database.SqlQuery<RegionDetails>("GetStats @regions", param);

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on @SteveD's answer but to clarify exactly what I did incase it helps any one else.
There was nothing wrong with my stored procedure. It was purely my calling of it. It needed the parameter name in the actual call like so:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();

            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            param.TypeName = "dbo.Regions";
            param.Value = myDataTable;
            param.ParameterName = "@regions";

return _context.Database.SqlQuery<RegionDetails>("GetStats @regions", param);
```