# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EventDateTime', table using datatable

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm inserting the data using datatable as stored procedure parameter however getting the exception for datetime column .

Here is exception

> "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EventDateTime', table ABC column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

here is my sql table and stored procedure

```
create table ABC(
[S] nvarchar(50) Not NULL,
[Type] nvarchar(50) Not NULL,
[R] nVarchar(50) Not NULL,
[C] int Not NULL,
[EventDateTime] datetime NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [pk_chillerstatus] 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([S] ASC, [Type] ASC, [R] ASC, [EventDateTime])
);


CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ABCType] AS TABLE (
[S] nvarchar(50),
[Type] nvarchar(50),
[R] nVarchar(50),
[C] int 
,[EventDateTime] datetime
);

create procedure [dbo].[spInsertABC]
(
@abc [dbo].[ABCType] READONLY
)
as
begin

INSERT INTO ABC(S, Type,R,C
,EventDateTime
) 
     SELECT p.S, p.Type,p.R,p.C
     ,p.EventDateTime
     FROM @abc p;
end;
```

Here is code C#

```
public DataTable GenerateDatatable(DateTime eventDateTime, string s)
 {
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     dt.Columns.Add("S", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("R", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("C", typeof(int));
     dt.Columns.Add("EventDateTime", typeof(DateTime));
     
    dt.Rows.Add(s, "E", "A", 0, eventDateTime);
    dt.Rows.Add(s, "E", "M", 2, eventDateTime);
    dt.Rows.Add(s, "E", "N", 3, eventDateTime);
    dt.Rows.Add(s, "E", "S", 4, eventDateTime);
    dt.Rows.Add(s, "E", "No", 5, eventDateTime);
  
    return dt;
 }
```

Calling stored procedure

```
public async Task AddABC()
 {
     try
     {
         DateTime eventDatetime = DateTime.Now;

         DataTable rdt = GenerateDatatable(eventDatetime, "R");

         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(devSqlConnectionString))
         {
             using (var com = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[spInsertABC]", con))
             {
                 con.Open();
                 com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                 com.CommandTimeout = 500;
                 SqlParameter sqlparam = new SqlParameter("@abc", rdt);
                 sqlparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                 sqlparam.TypeName = "dbo.ABCType";
                 com.Parameters.Add(sqlparam);
                 com.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw ex;
    }
 }
```

Please help me out . I'm stuck with this exception .

Comment: I am not too familiar with this approach, but try if doing this helps: set `parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured` where `parameter` is the `new SqlParameter("@abc", ...)`. Found out about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29507726/1220550).

Comment: @PeterB, Thank you for  replying to my question. I have tried your approach it didn't worked. getting same exception for EventDateTime

Comment: Did you try inspecting the contents of `eventDateTime` or the data table before calling the procedure?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, yes, it have value

Comment: What is "it"? `eventDateTime`? `rdt`? Both? Please be specific and add info to the question about how you verified that both are populated correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try like this, where you don't pass the data table until the type and type name have been set:

```
con.Open();
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com.CommandTimeout = 500;

SqlParameter pABC = new SqlParameter("@abc", SqlDbType.Structured);
pABC.TypeName = "dbo.ABCType";
pABC.Value = rdt;
com.Parameters.Add(pABC);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If that still doesn't work, then I'd again check the *contents* of `rdt`. Maybe there is an extra row or one of the values *is* `NULL`. SQL Server doesn't make up phantom constraint violations.

The next debugging step would be to create a second table, where that column *can* be `NULL`, have the procedure insert there, and inspect the data. (Or just temporarily change the existing table to allow `NULL` in that column.)

Or generate the equivalent code to test the insert using just T-SQL, e.g.

```sql
DECLARE @rdt dbo.ABCType;

INSERT @rdt(S, [Type], R, C, EventDateTime)
  VALUES(N'S', N'Type', N'R', 1, getdate());

EXEC dbo.spInsertABC @abc = @rdt;
```

If this works, then the problem is in C#; if it doesn't, then the problem is with the table. If the latter, it would likely be: check for triggers on the table ... maybe there is something that duplicates rows and isn't perfect. In that case it will say the exception comes from `procedure {trigger name}`, not `procedure spInsertABC`.

If you always use `DateTime.Now`, then you could also consider not manually populating that value in the first place, since the system can do it for you. You could either re-create the type like this:

```sql
,[EventDateTime] datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
-- though I suggest always using UTC to cut deltas
-- between apps, databases servers, and end users
```

And then remove that column from the `Rows.Add()` lines.

Or, you could leave the type unchanged, but still leave the value `NULL` in the data table (or let the code keep not populating it without figuring out why), and then in the procedure:

```sql
INSERT dbo.ABC(S,[Type],R,C,EventDateTime) 
  SELECT p.S, p.[Type], p.R, p.C,
    COALESCE(p.EventDateTime, GETDATE())
  FROM @abc AS p;
```

But I would really go through all of these steps and figure out where these date/time values are getting lost.